# Angular refresh on server returns 404 error - apache server using .htacess

Tags: angular, apache, .htaccess

I've have built my angular application using the command: `ng build --base-href ./ --prod` (I have also tried `ng build --base-href /index --prod` & `ng build --base-href ./index --prod` & `ng build --prod`). I then put the contents of the `dist` folder created on my apache server.

When I go from the main page to the another page by using the navigation bar, it works fine. This is set up using `router` in the application. But I press refresh then I get an `Error 404`. I've looked into this and read loads of things to try, I have read a long thread of git trying many different combinations.

I created a `.htaccess` in the same root as the `index.html` for my webpage.

I have seen this repeated many times and so my `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Why do I still get a 404 Error? Am I building the application incorrectly or there something in the `.htaccess` that I am missing?

If you need any more code from my application please let me know and I will add it, I didn't want to add code that might not be helpful.

**EDIT**
This is my `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { SettingsComponent } from './settings/settings.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Is your website @ the base of your URL or in a sub directory?

Comment: @Mathias it is a subdirectory. e.g http://servername/myapplication

Comment: Try modifying this in index.html to match that  -- <base href="/">

Comment: @Mathias I still get the same `Error 404`.

Comment: you changed it to <base href="/myapplication"> ?  If yes, adding your router code above may help someone to figure it out.

Comment: You changed it, then did another build?

Comment: Also the code of one of the links that are failing

Comment: @Mathias Yes, I ran `ng build --base-href /myapplication --prod` and still get `Error 404`. I shall add the router code now

Comment: Just "ng build --prod" is fine if you first modify this tag in index.html <base href="/myapplication">

Comment: @Mathias Just ran `ng build --prod` and modified the `<base href>` tag to match what you suggested and I still get the same error

Comment: @Mathias Thank you for your help but I have now resolved this issue. I found another `.htacess` document to try and set `<base href="./">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another version of the `.htaccess` file to try that looked at like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(api)/
RewriteRule .* index.html [PT,L]
```

And I set `<base href="./">` in the `index.html` once built. Or build it using `ng build --base-href ./ --prod`